# Development Of Desktop Application In PHP

Tags: php, desktop-application

I want to develop Desktop Application In Core PHP..Is it secure from client side????

It means is there any security that no one can show my code at client side...

Comment: how do you want to develop it? If the user needs to install it with an apache server then they can see it

Comment: will this be hosted on their server, or accessed from your own server? If it's on their system they'll have access, even if obfuscated.

Comment: php files are stored as normal files , that can be opened with notepad even.it is like you can see the HTML source code of any website .

Comment: Sorry, but your question doesn't make any sense.  Are you talking about security?  Or about keeping the code obfuscated?  Though my advice for anyone wanting to develop desktop applications is "Don't use PHP to develop desktop applications".  It's not what PHP is for.  Use the right tool for the job, don't try to contort the wrong tool into it.

Comment: Thank you GordonM..I am New to php so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is an interpreted language, not a compiled one. It's very unlikely that you'll be able to hide everything without using special tools. Even if you're building application in Java (which compiles to Java Bytecode) you can decompile the code and get something readable (most of the time).

How do you want to build it? The only toolkit I know supporting PHP is GTK+ and the version is really lacking behind: http://gtk.php.net/

If it's a desktop application, what's the client side then?

Comment: client side means whenever i will host application on my client single machine...

Answer (score 1):

If you mean hiding source code from viewing, no, it's not possible. However, you can obscure it using ioncube or other PHP source obfuscator.

I recommend taking a look on Python, as Python can be compiler to bytecode, meaning its source code cannot be viewed (though can be understood what it does from bytecode instructions).

You'll have almost no problem picking up Python if you know some PHP programming. Python has tkinter as its de-facto GUI library.

You can also take a look at Ruby, which is also a nice language and mostly uses tk or GTK for gui.

The reason I recommend picking up these languages is that you'll get more google results and online support on Python/ruby desktop app programming than on PHP GUI programming. 
There just aren't many people who use PHP on desktop and will provide assistance.

If your choice is to stay with PHP, then there's PHP-GTK (http://gtk.php.net/).

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a scripting language, hence the code has to be readable for the interpreter to read it line by line and parse it. It is not like C or Java where it gets compiled into a binary file. Unless there are ways to encrypt it, your end user will be able to read your source.

Answer (score 0):

While I have no clue why you would want to use PHP to make a desktop application, these are some facts

PHP is a scripting language that is parsed by a `cli` (command line interface) version of a php parser, or by one that is called by a webserver. If you run it as a "desktop application", what would be strange, you would ONLY have a "client side", and not as you would regularly have, a "server side".

As everything is now client side, they can see your code. You can ofcourse obfuscate it, but that will only get you a little bit.

So no, it is not secure.